# Force Authetication Method on Tortoise SVN Client

Tags: authentication, svn, client, tortoisesvn

Im using TortoiseSVN Client 1.9.4. On SVN Server I enabled both authentication options (Windows authentication and basic authentication). On some clients, I can't use Windows authentication, because it's users are in a domain the server can't see. The question is: "Can I somehow force the SVN-client to use basic authentication?" I know that if I clear the cached data, the client shows a window that lets me enter username and password. But it seems that the client first tries to use the windows authentication. This needs a lot of time and causes an login failure on server event log.

Comment: Why do you think that you can't use Integrated Windows Authentication on some of the machines? It's not "Windows Authentication" it's Integrated Windows Authentication and Basic Windows Authentication.

Comment: On some clients the users are in a domain, the server doesn't know. So I can't use integrated authentication which takes the computers credential to login. I want the client not to take these credetials but to ask the user to enter username and password.

Comment: do you know about Windows Credential Manager tool? That's what they should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks thanks to bahrep! Using Windows Credential Manager helped to avoid Authentication errors on Server. The Client no always uses the credentials entered in password tresor.